# how to prevent website access from root website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have multiple websites hosted on GoDaddy. I have one website in the root folder (`/`) and other websites on different folders under the root.

- `www.mydomain.com` at the `/`
- `www.something.com` in folder `/something`

If a user types the URL `www.mydomain.com/something` it displays the contents of website `www.something.com`.

I want the user to be redirected to `www.mydomain.com` if the he/she types any sub directory name after `www.mydomain.com`.

I have the following in the `.htaccess` file in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect anything in a sub-directory to root, for use in the root `.htaccess` file.

```
# Redirect anything in a sub-directory to root
# (any URL with a slash in it, not including the first one)
RewriteRule / / [R=301,L]
```

Remember all of your stylesheets, images, javascript etc. must not be in subdirectories as they won't work (they would be redirected to root too). Everything for the website must be in root with this approach.

Comment: Agreed. But it is what was asked for. I already pointed out that concern in my answer. It may be requested that way for future compatibility when new sites are added.

Comment: Just to clear up for anyone looking at this, since the comment was deleted saying there is a redirect loop here, so I deleted my response which looked strange out of context. There isn't a loop. It may look that way, but one must remember that in a `.htaccess` file the first slash is not present in the matched URL, so this would only match sub-directories. Personally I think it looks pretty cool! And nice and neat and compact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to / of something or somethingelse is accessed from mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(something|somethingelse)/ / [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: The question was to redirect "if they type any sub directory name" so this doesn't answer it. It only redirects specified sub-directories, not "any".

Comment: That is on purpose. Otherwise even directories like `mydomain.com/css/` or `mydomain.com/js/` will also be redirected to root.

Comment: It may be on purpose but it does not answer the question!

Comment: While answering thousands of answer on SO I have learnt that OPs can ask for anything but realize the consequences later.

Comment: Which is why I answered what was asked but pointed out the risk. You didn't even explain that he needs to add all subdirectories to the list, and that it wouldn't do what he asked exactly. If you had, I would not downvote. Allowing people to follow their own line of reasoning also helps them learn.